# Calling file.browse() in ActionScript3 via JavaScript triggers an error

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

This is the AS3 part:

```
import flash.net.FileReference;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
import flash.system.Security;

Security.allowDomain( "*" );

// file reference:
var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
ExternalInterface.addCallback( "bFile" , choose );

function choose():void{
    ExternalInterface.call( "alert( 'browse' )" );
    file.browse();
}
```

HTML part:

```
<object width="1px" height="1px">
<param name="movie" value="./ftest/uploader.swf">
<embed width="1px" height="1px" allowscriptaccess="always" id="uploader" src="./ftest/uploader.swf">
</object>
```

JS part:

```
$( "#uploader" )[ 0 ].bFile();
```

**UPDATE**: - [ The action called via clicking on a button ]

`$( "#uploader" )[ 0 ]` returns the object (just as if I used `getElementById`).

When triggered, alert is thrown with "broswe" in it, therefore, I know `choose()` is called.

**But** it gets no further.

I get these lines in every browser's console: Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.

Could you help me figure out what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe your problem is security related, the browse method must be called in direct response to a user interaction (KeyboardEvent or MouseEvent).  Read the specific detailed section in the docs about this:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#browse()

The part from the docs I'm referencing:

In Flash Player 10 and Flash Player 9 Update 5, you can only call this method successfully in response to a user event (for example, in an event handler for a mouse click or keypress event). Otherwise, calling this method results in Flash Player throwing an Error exception.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I know that. Just missed it in the post. I call this action via clicking on a button.

Comment: Well the problem is Flash Player run-time doesn't know about the click that javascript captured that ultimately makes the call, all it knows is the clicks or keyboard events that took place when it had focus so there's no way for the run-time to verify/know that this was actually in response to a click.  Am I correct in my quick assessment that the click is captured in JS then triggers a callback to the flash container?  In re-examining the code it appears so.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But how do I pass the event to AS? I'd tried `onclick='$( \"#uploader\" )[ 0 ].bFile( event )'` and `function choose( e:Event ):void` but it failed. I started to learn AS yesterday and, I guess, I'm missing the logic.

Comment: There is no way that I'm aware of to fake it out.  I've tried this before for other tasks where I attempted quite a few hacks to create an event that as closely as possible matched the event when it was in fact user generated.  There's something it's doing under the hood to stop any workarounds.  You just need the button to be in Flash to do this or you need to use something in JS to achieve the goal.  I believe the intention on their part is to avoid any security risk related to confusing a user into selecting a file on their file-system.

Comment: well... do you no whether it relates to sending AS URL requests via js?

Comment: @MichaelSazonov sorry I don't follow your last comment, you should be able to use any other RPC classes like URLRequest or HTTPService or whatever it's just the case with the File related classes since they have some limited level of access to the users file-system.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Also I'm going to defend my answer here unless someone else proves me wrong I believe even though this doesn't offer you a solution I am giving you valid information that is the correct answer even though it's not a solution.  A more valid workaround needs to be considered here, either the button or form used should be created in the flash context (within the container in the browser) or the functionality you desire should be done using Javascript/HTML (that's not my area of focus but this looks like it would do it http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_fileupload.asp).

Comment: I'm fully satisfied by your answer and comments. About your last comment - I can manage file upload via JS and PHP only, but there are features that can be evaluated using flash or ActiveX only (on common servers). Since ActiveX trusted by common users much less than flash - that made my choice.Thank you very much

Comment: @MichaelSazonov Thanks for accepting, I know it's frustrating when the answer is something like it can't be done, and as a developer I loathe giving that answer.  Best of luck.